# lodash's each not setting value for each item

Tags: lodash

I'm using lodash's `each` function to set some property on each item of my collection.

L1 `each(forms, form => form.isEditMode = false);`

L2 `each(forms, form => form.uuid = Math.random());`

L1 doesn't work.
L2 works.

Answer (score 0):

L1 basically never runs after the first item because as per docs `Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.` and assignment of `false` means it returns `false`.

I was pulling my hair until I got it.